# How to create js.Array inside js.Array in scalaJS for highcharts as specified in the documentation?

Tags: javascript, scala, highcharts, scala-collections, scala.js

I am working with highcharts in scalaJS. I want to create such [ [0, 1],[1, 2],[2, 8] ] JS array in scalaJS (basically 2D array)
What kind of parameters can be passed can be seen in this documentation :  [HighChart Documentation](https://karasiq.github.io/scalajs-highcharts/api/index.html#com.highcharts.config.SeriesLine@data:scala.scalajs.js.UndefOr[scala.scalajs.js.Array[scala.scalajs.js.|[scala.scalajs.js.|[com.highcharts.CleanJsObject[com.highcharts.config.SeriesLineData],scala.scalajs.js.Array[scala.scalajs.js.Any]],Double]]]) 
Need to override this array to `data` val of the class (see documentation)
How to create 2D array in scala of type specified in the documentation ?
Find a sample project [Here(GitHub)](https://github.com/rupinder1133/Highcharts-in-scalaJS).

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am unable to understand how to create a 2D array of the required type. Kindly help ! 
Thanks. @sjrd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Scaladoc, the expected type of `data` is:

```
js.UndefOr[js.Array[CleanJsObject[SeriesLineData] | js.Array[js.Any] | Double]]
```

That's a pretty awful beast, and the type inference has a hard time figuring it out. You can help the type inference enough like this:

```
val data: js.UndefOr[js.Array[CleanJsObject[SeriesLineData] | js.Array[js.Any] | Double]] =
  js.defined(js.Array(
      js.Array[js.Any](0, 1),
      js.Array[js.Any](1, 2),
      js.Array[js.Any](2, 8)
  ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I can't tell you for how long I was struggling for this , tried so many iteration. I would want to understand docs like that some day. Thank you so much !! @sjrd

Answer (score 0):

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js

val data = js.Array(
  js.Array(0, 1),
  js.Array(1, 2),
  js.Array(2, 8) 
)
```

Comment: Gives error :
type mismatch
`found`   : scala.scalajs.js.Array[scala.scalajs.js.Array[Int]]
   `required` : scala.scalajs.js.UndefOr[scala.scalajs.js.Array[scala.scalajs.js.|[scala.scalajs.js.|[com.highcharts.CleanJsObject[com.highcharts.config.SeriesLineData],scala.scalajs.js.Array[scala.scalajs.js.Any]],Double]]]
                     data = js.Array(
@Aleksey Fomkin
see documentation for proper required type.